# Access asp:CheckBox inner input from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, radio-button, css

I have a `jQuery` array acting on each control having corresponding `class`:

```
function Foobar() {
   $('.foo').each(function() {
     // do something with $(this)
   }
}
```

I can access client-side controls like `<input class="foo">` and server-side controls like <`asp:TextBox CassClass="foo">`

But setting `CssClass` for `asp:RadioButton` doesn't make a sense. Here is generated code:

```
<span class="foo">
   <input type="radio" />
</span>
```

How to set `class` for inner `input` or another way gather it using `jQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the inner input type radio elements in many ways, for example you could use the [`:radio`](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) selector:

```
$('.foo input:radio').each(function () {
  //...
});
```

Comment: Will it select controls with class="foo" theirself *and* inner controls of them?

Comment: It will select the `<input type="radio" />` elements whose have a parent with class `foo`.

Comment: If we need to select ONLY the radio buttons rendered by asp.net in the span tag, then this solution will not work methinks & thats where I think we need to the :only-child selector...

Answer (score 1):

```
function Foobar(){
 $('.foo input[type=radio]:only-child').each(function(){
   // do something with $(this)
 });
}
```